# how to set false to tabstop value for a label in C#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have a pretty complex UI with hundreds of control/label on it. I want to set tabstop value as false for each label as below

//in MyForm.designer.cs

Label myLabel;

private void InitializeComponent()

{

this.myLabel = new Label();

this.myLabel.TabIndex = 1;

...

}

// in MyForm.cs

this.myLabel.TabStop = false;

But it is not working. Is there any way to set the tabstop value so that tab is not stopped at myLabel??

Comment: I don't believe that the standard .NET labels have TabStop properties since they themselves never get focus. Is this a standard .NET label? If it is, I think the problem lies elsewhere, since the label isn't able to stop the tab, as far as I know.

Comment: I found that although we can set the TabSTop value, it is not used

//
        // Summary:
        //     Gets or sets a value indicating whether the user can tab to the System.Windows.Forms.Label.
        //     This property is not used by this class.
        //
        // Returns:
        //     This property is not used by this class. The default is false.
        [EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]

But somehow tab is lost between two buttons (with tabindex 0 and 2). I have a label (with tabindex 1) within these two buttons.

Comment: Labels do have a  TabStop Boolean property associated with them. In VS2015, often the controls will receive focus and it needs to be disabled, however, the TabStop property is not shown in the designer properties window.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using standard Label control, it should not get focus. Behavior of Label is to just forward focus to first control that can get it (e.g. TextBox). However, do notice that if you have control that can have input focus (e.g. TextBox), once that control gets focus, focus will stay with it regardless of TabStop property.

Comment: Old question, but VS2015 often creates labels with TabStop = True

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the tabindex to -1, that usually causes tabs to be skipped in most implementations that I have used.

Comment: Most implementations of what?

Comment: Most implementations of controls with a tabindex feature.  I thought that was obvious.

Comment: Negative one (-1) is an illegal value for tab index. Must be an integer greater than 0.

Comment: @mohnston wow old question to add a comment to but I thought I should reply.  Using -1 will cause the control to not be included in the tab order because of the invalid value.  So yes it must be greater than 0 if you want it to be used in the tab order but if not, using -1 causes the desired effect.

Comment: -1 is only an illegal value if you are using the designer Properties window. If you are in runtime code, or editing the designer file by hand, you can supply -1 as a TabIndex value.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
Private Sub Label1_Enter(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Label1.Enter
        SendKeys.Send("{TAB}")
    End Sub

Private Sub Label2_Enter(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Label2.Enter
    SendKeys.Send("{TAB}")
End Sub

Private Sub Label3_Enter(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Label3.Enter
    SendKeys.Send("{TAB}")
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```cs
(label as System.Windows.Forms.Control).TabStop = false;
```

Label control hides the TabStop property. It is annoying because one has to set its tab stop to be one less than tab stop of corresponding control, increasing number of tab stop indices. Loading controls dynamically is a pain unless one disables tab stops on labels and other non-input controls.

Note designer will intermittently toss an exception on line setting TapStop to false.